# Christoffel's Symbol's relation to the Metric Tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In chapter 9.2 of "Tensors, Relativity and Cosmology", the contracted Christoffel symbol of the second kind as a function of the metric tensor was defined as: $$\Gamma_{nm}^m=\frac{1}{2}\left(g^{mk}\frac{\partial g_{kn}}{\partial x^m}+g^{mk}\frac{\partial g_{mk}}{\partial x^n}-g^{mk}\frac{\partial g_{nm}}{\partial x^k}\right). \tag{9.30}$$

Which simplified into $$\Gamma_{nm}^m=\frac{1}{2}g^{mk}\frac{\partial g_{mk}}{\partial x^n}. \tag{9.31}$$

Later on an alternative expression was obtained (*the derivation was extremely lengthy so multiple steps ignored here)* using $g=g_{mk}G^{mk}$ :$$\Gamma_{nm}^m=\frac{1}{2g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^n}=\frac{\partial \ln\sqrt g}{\partial x^n} \tag{9.36}$$

Combining the results (9.31) and (9.36) gives $$\frac{1}{2}g^{kn}\frac{\partial g_{kn}}{\partial x^l}\frac{1}{2g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^l}=\frac{\partial \ln\sqrt g}{\partial x^l} \tag{9.45}$$

However, I was not able obtain the RHS of (9.45) and it looks like the RHS of (9.36) remains unaltered upon the combination with (9.30)? Could anyone explain how the RHS of (9.45) was yielded?

Comment: $\dfrac {\partial }{\partial x} \ln \left( g^{1/2}\left( x\right) \right) =\dfrac {1}{2g} \dfrac {\partial g}{\partial x}
$

Comment: @Eli I did understand where this came from but the question is how multiplying 9.31 with 9.36 gives $\frac{\partial \ln\sqrt g}{\partial x^l}$ ?

Comment: Hi EXINT. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic♦ Hi, I'll have a read but the tag was actually added by another user who edited my question earlier on.

Comment: That user was me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have this book (it would be good to add a better reference to it: I *assume* it is [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/C2014-0-03846-4)), but I am almost certain that the (9.45) is wrong as given (in v2 / v4 of the question: I don't know what's in the book).  Even without looking hard at it it's clear that it's syntactically dubious, at best: it contains a repeated index ($l$) on the LHS which can't sensibly be summed over and which corresponds to an *unrepeated* index on the RHS: that simply makes no sense in terms of the ESC.

I believe that (9.45) is simply missing an equals sign and should read:

$$
\frac{1}{2}g^{kn} \frac{\partial g_{kn}}{\partial x^l}
 = \frac{1}{2g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^l}
 = \frac{\partial\ln\left(\sqrt{g}\right)}{\partial x^l}
$$

This is merely equating the expressions in (9.31) & (9.36).

I think a way of checking this would be to see what further use they make of (9.45): my guess is either 'none' or they use the corrected version above.